# pyspark groupBy and orderBy use together

Tags: python, sorting, pyspark, group-by, sql-order-by

Hi there I want to achieve something like this

```
SAS SQL: select * from flightData2015 group by DEST_COUNTRY_NAME order by count
```

My data looks like this:
[image]

This is my spark code:

```
flightData2015.selectExpr("*").groupBy("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME").orderBy("count").show()
```

I received this error:

AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'orderBy'. I am new to pyspark. Pyspark's groupby and orderby are not the same as SAS SQL?

I also try sort`flightData2015.selectExpr("*").groupBy("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME").sort("count").show()`and I received kind of same error. "AttributeError: 'GroupedData' object has no attribute 'sort'"
Please help!

Comment: As you are not aggregating per group, you can simply order by two columns to get a similar effect. `df.orderBy(['DEST_COUNTRY_NAME', 'count']).show()`.

Comment: Why are you grouping and not calculating any aggregate results per group?  Or did you mean that last word `count` in your SQL to reference the COUNT(*) aggregate function result instead of some existing variable named COUNT?

Comment: @Tom, OP has `count` column in the dataframe (in image).  I am guessing OP is asking for ordering.  Aggregation is already done.  @Shawn11, does orderBy with 2 columns works for you, is that what you are asking for?

Comment: It does look like the original SQL is wrong.  It should not have the group by clause at all as it only needs an order by clause.

Comment: Thank you so much! I think in his case I will only use order by

Comment: It seems you are already familiar with SQL, why not using it for Spark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for group by if you want every row.
You can order by multiple columns.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
vals = [("United States", "Angola",13), ("United States","Anguilla" , 38), ("United States","Antigua", 20), ("United Kingdom", "Antigua", 22), ("United Kingdom","Peru", 50), ("United Kingdom", "Russisa",13), ("Argentina", "United Kingdom",13),]
cols = ["destination_country_name","origin_conutry_name", "count"]



df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
#display(df.orderBy(['destination_country_name', F.col('count').desc()])) If you want count to be descending

display(df.orderBy(['destination_country_name', 'count']))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spark, `groupBy` returns a `GroupedData`, not a DataFrame. And usually, you'd always have an aggregation after `groupBy`. In this case, even though the SAS SQL doesn't have any aggregation, you still have to define one (and drop it later if you want).

```py
(flightData2015
    .groupBy("DEST_COUNTRY_NAME")
    .count() # this is the "dummy" aggregation
    .orderBy("count")
    .show()
)
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the reply. I want to group the data by DEST_COUNTRY_NAME, and in the same DEST_COUNTRY_NAME, rank the "count". I want to retain each row but when I use agg function. I only get 1 row for each  DEST_COUNTRY_NAME

Comment: You're grouping by `DEST_COUNTRY_NAME`, so that is expected. Can you show the output of the SQL?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is relevant to Spark 3.x and is slight modification to @greenie's answer.

**Defining the dataset**

```
vals = [("United States", "Angola",13), ("United States","Anguilla" , 38), ("United States","Antigua", 20), ("United Kingdom", "Antigua", 22), ("United Kingdom","Peru", 50), ("United Kingdom", "Russisa",13), ("Argentina", "United Kingdom",13),]
cols = ["destination_country_name","origin_conutry_name", "count"]
```

**Creating the dataframe**

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, cols)
```

**Applying `groupBy` and `orderBy` together**

```
df.groupBy("destination_country_name").count().sort(desc("count")).show()
```

The **result** will look like this:

```
+------------------------+-----+
|destination_country_name|count|
+------------------------+-----+
|          United Kingdom|    3|
|           United States|    3|
|               Argentina|    1|
+------------------------+-----+
```